# APP suddenly die with React Devtool under windows system

Tags: react-native

I init a new RN 0.40 project under win10( brand new system ) or win 7, didn't modify any code, run it on a real Android device.

If I do not choose 'debug in Chrome', the APP runs well.

But if I choose 'debug in Chrome', the APP would run for a liitle while then exit suddenly.

My React Devtool is 0.14.6.

And below is the log in Android Studio when exit.

01-13 14:19:12.545 24105-28940/com.learnrn I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 408625(107MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 20MB/34MB, paused 10.528ms total 235.319ms
01-13 14:19:12.545 24105-24105/com.learnrn I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 155.528ms for cause Alloc
01-13 14:19:25.805 24105-29639/com.learnrn W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1064960-byte stack: Out of memory
01-13 14:19:25.805 24105-29639/com.learnrn E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
01-13 14:19:25.805 24105-29639/com.learnrn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                             Process: com.learnrn, PID: 24105
                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1338)
                                                                 at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.put(ConnectionPool.java:135)
                                                                 at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$1.put(OkHttpClient.java:149)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:33)
                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:120)
                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-13 14:19:25.855 24105-24105/com.learnrn D/SensorManager: unregisterListener ::
01-13 14:19:25.885 24105-24166/com.learnrn W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1064960-byte stack: Out of memory
01-13 14:19:25.885 24105-24166/com.learnrn E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
01-13 14:19:25.885 24105-24166/com.learnrn W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1064960-byte stack: Out of memory
01-13 14:19:25.885 24105-24166/com.learnrn E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
01-13 14:19:25.885 24105-24166/com.learnrn I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24105 SIG: 9